# ScrollView or FlatList inside MaterialTopNavigator: pull to refresh doesn't work on some iOS devices(X, X Max, 8 Plus)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a *FlatList* with *RefreshControl* inside a TabNavigator created by `createMaterialTopTabNavigator`. When I try to pull down to refresh, it works very on Android, and small iPhones like 7/8/6s/5s/SE. However for larger iPhones (X, X max, XR, 8 Plus, etc), I can't pull to refresh if the scroll view is at the top. I have to scroll down a little then go back up to pull in order to refresh the view. When the scroll goes back to top, it will stop responding to pull actions. Bottom Tab Bars created from `createBottomTabNavigator` works fine.

I'm wondering if this is a bug of MaterialTopTabNavigator and what are the possible solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

install the latest version of react-navigation-tabs and import directly from react-navigation-tabs instead of react-navigation fixed the issue

`npm i -S react-navigation-tabs`

`import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-tabs";`